# How navigate back to search page?

Tags: javascript, session, meteor, navigation, iron-router

What is the Meteor/Iron Router way to jump back to a search page after visiting the single view result? I'm using `history.back()` at the moment, but it sometimes messes up. And it won't work for visitors that land directly on the single view page. I'm trying out Session but I'm not sure what parameters are good practice to use. Or maybe there's another approach? Thanks! ~ Kai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually iron:router have a method called `Location.back()`

Also seems like `history.back()` its a good option too.

Check this [Add 'previousPage' and 'backMethods'](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router/pull/92) or [this feature request](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/48)

If you only want to do this on the `search template` try with this code.

```
// onStop offshoot is executed whenever we LEAVE a lane
Router.onStop(function(){
  // register the previous route into a Session
  Session.set("previousLocation",this.location.path);
});

// onBeforeAction is executed before indeed going to a new lane
Router.onBeforeAction(function(){
  // getting the previous route
  var previousLocationPath=Session.get("previousLocation");
  // now lets back to search route.
  if(previousLocation ==="/search"){
    this.redirect("search");
  }
  this.next();
});
```

Take this code from this [Previous Page location on ironRouter](http://anchufive.org/adeline/2015/01/30/previous-page-location-on-ironrouter/) tutorial